# ffplay window content blurry with HiDPI

Tags: macbook-pro, display, command-line, resolution

I'm streaming the screen of a tablet (a [reMarkable](https://remarkable.com/)) on my 2017 13-inch MacBook Pro, which has a 2560 x 1600 pixel screen. I use a script called reStream from [this GitHub repository](https://github.com/rien/reStream), which renders the screen of the tablet on the computer display with

```
ffplay -vcodec rawvideo \
         -loglevel "$loglevel" \
         -f rawvideo \
         -pixel_format gray16le \
         -video_size "1408,1872" \
         -i -
```

I'm experiencing a problem with the ffplay window, which is blurry unless I disable the HiDPI mode on my mac. Below are two screenshots, the first one taken with a 1280 x 800 (retina) resolution, the second one with the native 2560 x 1600. They are both full-screen screnshots. And of course the ffplay input is identical in both cases.

Does anyone know why the video stream in retina mode is blurry and how I could fix that? Thank you!

[image: 1st screenshot, resolution: retina 1280 x 800]
[image: 2nd screenshot, resolution: 2560 x 1600]

Comment: Is the `video_size` correct?

Comment: @Allan Yes, I double checked the tablet specs and also tried to change the values: changing the width shifts all lines relative to the previous one, changing the height makes the bottom part of the screen disappear or adds black pixels on the bottom